# law of iterated logrithm

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, on which
$\mathcal{F}_t$ is filtration satisfying general conditions. $W_t$ is
a standard Brownian motion. By law of iterated logarithm, one has
$$ P\Big(\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{W_t}{t} = 0\Big) = 1 $$
This implies
$$ P\Big(\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t + W_t}{t} = 1\Big) = 1. \quad (1)$$
We have contradiction in this below. By Girsanov theorem, there exists
a probability measure $Q$ equivalent to $P$, such that $t+ W_t$ is a
Brownian motion w.r.t. $Q$. By law of iterated logarithm,
$$ Q\Big(\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t + W_t}{t} = 0\Big) = 1, $$
which implies
$$ P\Big(\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t + W_t}{t} = 0\Big) = 1, \quad (2)$$
since $P$ is equivalent to $Q$.
Why does this argument leads to a contradiction between (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Girsanov's theorem tells you that on any *finite* interval $[0,T]$ you can find an equivalent probability that makes $t+B_t$ a Brownian motion. You just gave the proof that it cannot be done on the whole real line.

Comment: Or in other word this shows that $P$ and $Q$ are mutually sigular with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}=\Vee_{t}\mathcal{F}_t$.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that (1) is not correct, since the law of the iterated logarithm states that
$$|B_t|\approx \sqrt{2t\log\log(1/t)}$$
as $t\to0$. This yields
$$\frac{|B_t|}{t}\to\infty$$
as $t\to0$

Comment: sorry, I want $t\to \infty$ for all the above limits.
Those are typos.